# Solutions for user testing during WFH?

Tags: user-research, usability-testing, testing

It's been really tough trying to do user-testing through Zoom. Really struggling. Do any of you have any suggestions? Have you been facing similar problems? Any hacks?

Thanks!

Comment: Maze testing has been a great platform for us.

Comment: Do you mind giving examples of what your are finding really tough? That will help to provide a good hack/idea.

Comment: If this is a question strictly about software recommendations (even though it is in a UX context), then it falls outside of the scope of UXSE (and may have to be closed). But if you can identify specific issues with the software and compare it to other software applications that address the usability issues (for example), then it is suitable for this forum.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, It's a very difficult time for us as a designers to do user testing these days. I'd like to suggest https://maze.design/ and https://preely.com/ for mobile prototype testing.

Answer (score 1):

There are different tools around: from full-service to do everything on your own.

I can recommend https://lookback.io for qualitative recordings.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Miro](https://miro.com/) to conduct a remote user research session over Zoom. (plus it is free)

It allows you to create boards with post its and the person you are conducting the session with can collaborate on the same board and add more post its + content. This is a helpful case study for inspiration: https://miro.com/blog/melewi-remote-ux-research/

[image: Miro example]

Image source: https://miro.com/blog/using-miro-to-run-remote-meetings-workshops/